# How can I Queue an asynchronous operation in Quandis Business Objects?

Tags: qbo3

I want to call a QBO3 operation asynchronously, using the Queue behavior.

How can I push a method call to a QBO3 queue using the Quandis REST Api and/or Javascript?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the basic pattern for Javascript:

```
object = new qbo3.{className}()
object.invoke('Queue/{methodName}', { 'QueueName': '{queueName}', ... })
```

A raw REST call with a URL would follow this pattern:

```
{domain}/{className}/{handler}.ashx/Queue/{methodName}?{parameters}
```